# Linq to Entities with multiple related entities performance and UNIONs

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, projection

I'm building search logic (for an MVC application) and to put it simply - I'm stuck!

I've spent a few days building the Linq to Entities query to use projection. All was well on the surface until I looked at the generated SQL statement underneath. Gasp!

I next spent another few more days trying to rid these UNION statements from the SQL statements, trying JOINs, FROMs, INCLUDEs, anything that would just give me inner/left outer joins with the related entities loaded.

But I haven't been able to do this successfully and still stuck at this point.

Some points to consider:

- L2E query contains multiple related (child) entities with projection (no issue here unless this is a bad design, i.e. causing the UNIONs)
- Created summary classes that fit the anonymous types, e.g. StudentSummary
- Summary classes only contain a few of the columns of the entity object's columns for performance reasons - don't need to return all columns on initial search
- Recently started using PredicateBuilder to return students from a search, e.g. male students with a specialization... All good in this area (so far).

Here is what I've done so far (code changed to hide proprietary property - may have typos):

```
    query = from s in context.Students
    select new StudentSummary
    {
        StudentID = s.StudentID,
        Title = s.Title,
        FullName = s.FullName,
        Qualifications = s.Qualifications,
        Gender = s.Gender,
        CampusSummaries = (
                    from c in s.Campuses
                    select new CampusSummary
                    {
                        Name = c.Name,
                        LocationSummary = new LocationSummary
                        {
                            State = c.Location.State
                        }
                    }),
                    SpecializationSummaries = (
                                    from sp in s.StudentSpecializations
                                    select new StudentSpecializationSummary
                                        {
                                            StudentSpecializationID = sp.StudentSpecializationID,
                                            SpecializationSummary = new SpecializationSummary
                                            {
                                                Name = s.Specialization.Name
                                            }
                                        }),
                    SubSpecializationSummaries = (
                                    from ssp in s.StudentSubSpecializations
                                    select new StudentSubSpecializationSummary
                                        {
                                            StudentSubSpecializationID = ssp.StudentSubSpecializationID,
                                            SubSpecializationSummary = new SubSpecializationSummary
                                            {
                                                Name = s.SubSpecialization.Name
                                            }
                                        })
};
```

My projection statements appear to make Entity Framework generate the following SQL UNION statements, below is a snippet only (code changed to hide proprietary property - may have typos):

```
{SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[StudentID] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[StudentID1] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[Title] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[FullName] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[Qualifications] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[Gender] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[StudentSpecializationID] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll1].[StudentSpecializationID1] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll1].[StudentSpecializationID2] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C17]
FROM  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[StudentSpecializationID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
    [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID1], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
    [Extent1].[Qualifications] AS [Qualifications], 
    [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    [Join1].[StudentSpecializationID] AS [StudentSpecializationID], 
    [Join1].[StudentSpecializationID] AS [StudentSpecializationID1], 
    [Join1].[StudentSpecializationID] AS [StudentSpecializationID2], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5]
    FROM  [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[StudentSpecializationID] AS [StudentSpecializationID], [Extent2].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM  [dbo].[StudentSpecialization] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Specialization] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[SpecializationID] = [Extent3].[SpecializationID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[StudentID] = [Join1].[StudentID]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Extent4].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
    [Extent4].[StudentID] AS [StudentID1], 
    [Extent4].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent4].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
    [Extent4].[Qualifications] AS [Qualifications], 
    [Extent4].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
    [Join3].[StudentSubSpecializationID] AS [StudentSubSpecializationID], 
    [Join3].[StudentSubSpecializationID] AS [StudentSubSpecializationID1], 
    [Join3].[StudentSubSpecializationID] AS [StudentSubSpecializationID2], 
    [Join3].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[StudentSubSpecializationID] AS [StudentSubSpecializationID], [Extent5].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], [Extent6].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM  [dbo].[StudentSubSpecialization] AS [Extent5]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SubSpecialization] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[SubSpecializationID] = [Extent6].[SubSpecializationID] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent4].[StudentID] = [Join3].[StudentID]) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[StudentID1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC}
```

I'm not sure why are UNIONs being used here. Perhaps I'm using projection poorly. Although I have noticed when two or more projections are included in your L2E statement then UNIONS appears in SQL.

I've tried going in another direction by removing the projections but unsuccessfully tried using Joins, Froms... just can't seem to get the related child entities being returned.

I can't use Include as I'm using my summary objects for performance reasons.

I'm also questioning if I'm going about this correctly now, i.e. am I going in the right direction of returning nested related (child) entities?!?! Perhaps I should be returning flat results, e.g. Students, Campuses, Specializations... objects all at the same level, i.e. remove the hierarchy.

**Question**:

If I built this with T-SQL I would be using INNER & LEFT OUTER JOINs to return the related child nested entities and also filter students. This is what I'm trying to achieve with Linq to Entities. How can I do this? E.g. with joins, projection, or whatever... (without the UNIONs and Cast(NULL)s...

Appreciate any help, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction, as I'm really stuck here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query performing badly? If not, don't worry about the generated sql. Using an `union all` may in fact be the best way to accomplish this. Creating one very complex query with multiple joins may be slower than multiple simple queries combined with an `union all`

Comment: Query isn't running poorly with small numbers of records, but I would need to do SQL profiling to find out for sure. But good point re union all vs multiple joins - didn't think of this. Will read up on this to confirm. Thanks, this helps.